# Rocket core risc-v , Load and store at memory address not going through

Tags: riscv

i am using risc-v, rocket core.
I want to do some basic READ/WRITE operations at a given address.
Ran all the testcases available in testsuite. All testcase are passing(including ld and store).
Now write a simple c testcase to load at particular address, compiled and  ran testcase. Testcase is not going through.

```
int main ()
{
      *((volatile unsigned int*)0x8000F000)  = 0x600D600D;
}
```

Generated the asm code for same and pasted the code in  testcase available in testsuite. Still testcase is not going through.
Command c2object
    riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc  -DENTROPY=18590 -static -mcmodel=medany        -fvisibility=hidden -nostdlib -nostartfiles -I./../env/p -I./macros/scalar -T./../env/p/link.ld mem_wr_tc.c -o mem_wr_tc.o

Object to Assembly
    riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump --disassemble-all --disassemble-zeroes --section=.text --section=.text.startup --section=.text.init --section=.data mem_wr_tc.o > mem_wr_tc.asm

Has anyone tried a basic store\load (read\write ) to a particular address.

please suggest, what could go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things you should do:

1) Look at the disassembly to verify the program is what you expect it to be. It appears you are trying to build a bare-metal program, so your disassembly will need the proper start-up code at the proper physical addresses.

2) Try your program in spike (single-stepping), and verify your program is working properly.

3) Look at the standard output from rocket, which will tell you what it is doing every cycle.

4) Analyze the rocket-chip memory map, to make sure you are writing to the correct physical address.

5) analyze the VCD waveform to see what rocket is doing when it attempts to perform your memory operations at that particular address.